# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unique'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, zeroconf

I installed zeroconf on a linux machine running Fedora 20. I have installed all the packages on which zeroconf depends on. However, when I try to run testcert.py, I come across the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testcert.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _mdns
  File "/opt/home/gcp_cert_test/_mdns.py", line 23, in <module>
    from zeroconf import InterfaceChoice
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeroconf-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/zeroconf.py", line 1257, in <module>
    @enum.unique
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

Do I need to install any other packages? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Isn't any module of yours masking the `enum` module. Don't you have a `enum.py ` some where else in the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: How do I find out which module is masking the enum module? Currently, I have enum and enum-compat installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Comment: What about `import enum; print enum`?

Comment: Here's what I get: print enum
<module 'enum' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum-0.4.6-py2.7.egg/enum.pyc'> . So that works fine.

Answer (score 7):

The problme is caused by having installed both [`enum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum) and `enum-compat` which installs [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

Both `enum` and `enum34` expose the same namespace, a top-level package called `enum`. `zeroconf` will assume that it's loading `enum` from `enum34` package.

If you don't need `enum`, I'll recommend you to uninstall it.
Otherwise use a `virtualenv`, so you can have both `enum34` and `enum` installed in different enviroments for different packages.

Comment: Thank you @memoselyk . That recommendation worked. I removed enum and enum-compat and just installed enum34 from source. This install enum too.

Comment: You're welcome! Just one clarification, the `enum-compat` package makes the [`enum` package](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html) available on python earlier than 3.4. So it's better if you only make sure that `enum` is not installed and let `enum-compat` install `enum34` if required.